# Why do we use cout and cin for fcgi apps?

Tags: c++, fastcgi

Is there a reason we override {`cin/cout/cerr`}'s streambuf in fcgi apps when handling the fcgi requests?

I'm looking at the example fcgi app at http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/echo-cpp.cpp and notice they set the `streambufs` of `cin/cout/cerr` to those of the fcgi request rather than create a new `istream/ostreams` to wrap the `streambufs` in the `main(void)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Makes life simpler.

Have the moral equivalent for Perl, PHP etc. to send output to the browser.

Also handy for testing.

Comment: Is it just pure convention? I'm assuming it would be safe to create an istream and pass the fcgi_streambuf(request.in) into it and use that for the fcgi_{in/out}.

how is it handy for testing?

Comment: Handy for testing - just run the CGI script on the command line.

Comment: hm how would you run this one on the command line exactly? 

I've tried running ./echo-cpp after compiling it and it just terminates (I'm guessing FCGX_Accept_r() just returns non-zero).